# Joining mysql tables twice to the same column

Tags: mysql

I have a table `users` with column `profile_image` and `cover_image` both of these point to `id` in TABLE `images`.

```
TABLE images (
  id,
  url,
  description,
  ...
)

TABLE users (
  profile_image (foreign key ON images.id),
  cover_image (foreign key ON images.id),
  ...
)
```

I want to retrieve:

1. `images.url AS profile_image` after joining `users.profile_image = images.id`
2. and `images.url AS cover_image` after joining `users.cover_image = images.id`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could join twice as follows:

```
SELECT i.url AS profile_image, i2.url AS cover_image
FROM users u
INNER JOIN images i on u.profile_image = i.id
INNER JOIN images i2 on u.cover_image = i2.id
WHERE u.id = ....
```

I would also suggest naming foreign keys like `profile_image_id` and `cover_image_id` so that it is clear that the column points to some kind of an ID in a foreign table. Try to follow this convention.

Comment: @user3564573 updated the answer with a suggestion. FYI, there is another site http://dba.stackexchange.com which this SQL question seems to fit better to than this stackoverflow.